# I Want To Build Dataset From Scratch For My Project

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, dataset

I'm studying image processing with opencv and machine learning in python 
i started learn about SVM i want to build my own dataset i tried to download dataset and used scikit learn datasets but i want my own dataset from scratch is there a tutorial for building dataset or anyone can tell me how to do it?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a small amount of training data and from it, you can use following algorithms to generate more amount of training data and create your own dataset.

- [Bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating)
- [Cross-Validation (K Folds)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#k-fold_cross-validation)